# random number needed

Tags: bash, command-line, random

I need a command line script that will generate a random integer between 1 and 6.  I'm using Ubuntu with bash.
I was working on this a couple of months ago using 'bc', but never got it to work completely. I've since forgotten where I got to.

I'm using this to change a crontab script so that it will not always run every 15 minutes, but at random times (15+-3 minutes). ie. change the crontab to be every 12 minutes, and then in the script sleep for 1-6 minutes before running the script (which is basically a wget to check on the status of a webpage).

Comment: http://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 8):

See man bash, *PARAMETERS* section, *Shell Variables* subsection:

> ```
> RANDOM Each time this parameter is referenced, a random integer between
>        0 and 32767 is generated.  The sequence of random numbers may be
>        initialized by assigning a value to RANDOM.  If RANDOM is unset,
>        it loses its special properties, even if it is subsequently
>        reset.
> ```

To restrict the value to the 1..6 interval use the `$((RANDOM%6+1))` expression.
1

Or you can use `/dev/urandom` as follows:

```
tr -dc '1-6' < /dev/urandom | head -c 1
```

Comment: Definitely use /dev/urandom or /dev/random (slower) if you need more than just colloquially random numbers.

Comment: `/dev/random` isn't just slower, it *blocks* if the entropy pool is drained. Though I suspect a random number in the range 1–6 is probably going to be used for something simple. If the OP is planning on using it for encryption, the RNG period is probably the least of their problems. :)

Comment: I'm using this to change a crontab script so that it will not always run every 15 minutes, but at random times (15+-3 minutes).

Comment: @Alexios: `/dev/urandom` is almost always a better choice than `/dev/random`. See [this question](http://superuser.com/q/359599/92954) and [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/359601/92954).

Comment: @manatwork Your first solution does not work!!!                                 
     #!/bin/bash
     SLPTIME=$((RANDOM%6+1))m
     echo $SLPTIME        
It always give 1m when run in a script. When I run it from the commandline it works.  (Why can't I format anything in these damn comments!)

Comment: @manatwork The second method (/dev/urandom) requires <ENTER> to be pressed when run in a script! What am I doing wrong? [code follows. Each line ends with ']' so you can see what I'm doing] benson@SciSrv|08:55:/home/benson/scripts>cat abc]
#!/bin/bash]
#SLPTIME=$((RANDOM%6+1))m]
SLPTIME=`tr -dc '1-6' < /dev/urandom | head -c 1`]

echo $SLPTIME]

benson@SciSrv|08:55:/home/benson/scripts>./abc]
5]
benson@SciSrv|08:55:/home/benson/scripts>]
benson@SciSrv|08:55:/home/benson/scripts>]
[Notice the two command prompts at the end. I had to press <ENTER> before the script would stop.]

Comment: @GrandSatrap, multiline code in comments look bad. Better post it on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/). supposing your script contains `SLPTIME=\`tr -dc '1-6' < /dev/urandom | head -c 1\``, that works for me without the need of any keypress.

Comment: @manatwork The first method ($RANDOM) works now. I have no idea why it was always giving me the same number when I first tried it. The second method, doing the same thing as indicated in your previous comment doesn't work until I press a key. See http://pastebin.com/YRT50yyv   P.S. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GrandSatrap, I tested the code you pasted on Ubuntu and still works for me: http://pastebin.com/yVjED9qA . I would check that /dev/urandom is a device (not a symlink to /dev/random or something else) and `tr` and `head` are executable binaries in the /usr/bin/ directory, installed from the _coreutils_ package (I always had problems with _busybox_).

Comment: @manatwork   Well, this is now working too. I just followed the steps you did, but didn't change anything. Everything looks exactly as yours does. It turns out that the server which will be running this is on an older version of Ubuntu. However, it worked fine on both computers. I don't know why it didn't work yesterday. I rebooted my home desktop yesterday after apt-get upgrade, but the server has been up for 34 days.  Thanks for your help. I'm sure that you have better things to do. Are you some sort of Linux guru?

Answer (score 0):

I can propose a custom linear congruential random generator or X(n+1) = (343*X(n) ) % M17
where, M17= 2^17 - 1 = 131071 is the Mersenne prime number (p=17).
The pseudorandom sequence is uniformly distributed with a range [0,131070] then you can limit the range to [1,6[ as follows: Z6 = 6*X(n)/M17 + 1

Sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash
M=6    #change this if you need different ranges
let "z=(343*10#`date +%N`)%131071"
let "z=$M*z/131071+1"
echo $z
```

This is a one-shot random generator. If you need a random sequence, then the seed `10#date +%N`shall be used only once to start and the generator shall be used in a loop.
Tested on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. 
Have fun!