# Generate random numbers in specific range

Tags: shell, command-line, command, random

After googling a bit I couldn't find a simple way to use a shell command to generate a random decimal integer number included in a specific range, that is between a minimum and a maximum.

I read about `/dev/random`, `/dev/urandom` and `$RANDOM`, but none of these can do what I need.

Is there another useful command, or a way to use the previous data?

Comment: See this SO Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988824/generating-random-number-in-bash-shell-script as well as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556190/random-number-from-a-range-in-a-bash-script.

Comment: Possibly related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42045/random-number-needed/42046#42046

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124478/how-to-randomize-the-output-from-seq

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In the POSIX toolchest, you can use `awk`:

```
awk -v min=5 -v max=10 'BEGIN{srand(); print int(min+rand()*(max-min+1))}'
```

Do *not* use that as a source to generate passwords or secret data for instance, as with most `awk` implementations, the number can easily be guessed based on the time that command was run.

With many `awk` implementations, that command run twice within the same second will generally give you the same output.

Comment: +1.. As used in a script to assign output to a variable (w/o introducing a newline character and using zero padding for two places): `x=$(awk -v min=$min_var -v max=$max_var 'BEGIN{srand(); printf("%.2d", int(min+rand()*(max-min+1)))}')`

Comment: It's based on time? since I got the same value in 2 consecutive runs...

Comment: @ShaiAlon the current time is often used as the default seed value for srand() so usually, yes it's based on time, see Stéphane's sentence about that in his answer. You can get around that by changing the initial seed to a random number with `awk -v min=5 -v max=10 -v seed="$(od -An -N4 -tu4 /dev/urandom)" 'BEGIN{srand(seed+0); print int(min+rand()*(max-min+1))}'`. You could use `$RANDOM` instead of `od ... /dev/random` but then your seed value is in the relatively small range of 0 to 32767 and so you'll probably get noticeable repetitions in your output over time.

Comment: I've been burned too many times by various awk implementations' bad randomization to trust them, which is why [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/766331/87770) (also portable and pure posix) uses `od` on `/dev/urandom`

Answer (score 198):

You can try `shuf` from GNU coreutils:

```
shuf -i 1-100 -n 1
```

Comment: This also works with Busybox `shuf`.

Comment: Works in raspbian and GitBash too.

Comment: even with "-n 500" it only create 101 lines for me

Comment: The -n 1 part picks the 'top' line from a shuffle of the text list of numbered lines 1 to 100.  If you want 101 numbers you'd need to run this 101 total times.

Comment: `shuf -i 1000-9999 -n 256 -o file_name.txt` - generates *unique* 256 numbers from 1000 to 9999 and saves them into file named `file_name.txt`.

Comment: If you get less than `-n` probably you have a too-small range of numbers (ex. from 1 to 10 when -n 100) and you need to set a `-r` flag to get numbers *repeatedly*.
For example: `shuf -i 1-10 -n 30 -r` gets 30 *non-unique* numbers from 1 to 10

Comment: To be absolutely sure, one can add `--random-source=/dev/urandom` at the very end of the command. As a matter of fact, the default is not mentioned in the [official `shuf` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html). Above addition is suggested though in the [random sources documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Random-sources.html).

Answer (score 46):

## jot

On BSD and OSX you can use *jot* to return a single random (`-r`) number from the interval `min` to `max`, inclusive.

```
$ min=5
$ max=10
$ jot -r 1 $min $max
```

### Distribution problem

Unfortunately, the range and distribution of randomly generated numbers is influenced by the fact that jot uses double precision floating point arithmetic internally and printf(3) for output format, which causes rounding and truncation issues. Therefore, the interval's `min` and `max` are generated less frequently as demonstrated:

```
$ jot -r 100000 5 10 | sort -n | uniq -c
9918  5
20176 6
20006 7
20083 8
19879 9
9938  10
```

On OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) this appears to have been fixed:

```
$ jot -r 100000 5 10 | sort -n | uniq -c
16692 5
16550 6
16856 7
16579 8
16714 9
16609 10
```

and...

```
$ jot -r 1000000 1 10 | sort -n | uniq -c
100430 1
99965 2
99982 3
99796 4
100444 5
99853 6
99835 7
100397 8
99588 9
99710 10
```

### Solving the distribution problem

For older versions of OS X, fortunately there are several workarounds. One is to use printf(3) integer conversion. The only caveat is that the interval maximum now becomes `max+1`. By using integer formatting, we get fair distribution across the entire interval:

```
$ jot -w %i -r 100000 5 11 | sort -n | uniq -c
16756 5
16571 6
16744 7
16605 8
16683 9
16641 10
```

### The perfect solution

Finally, to get a fair roll of the dice using the workaround, we have:

```
$ min=5
$ max_plus1=11  # 10 + 1
$ jot -w %i -r 1 $min $max_plus1
```

### Extra homework

See [jot(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/jot.1?query=jot) for the gory math and formatting details and many more examples.

Answer (score 18):

The `$RANDOM` variable is normally not a good way to generated good random values. The output of `/dev/[u]random` need also to be converted first.

An easier way is to use higher level languages, like e.g. python:

To generate a random integer variable between 5 and 10 (5<=N<=10), use

```
python -c "import random; print random.randint(5,10)"
```

Do not use this for cryptographic applications.

Comment: This was useful. Thank you very much :) As signed often has worked with Unix->Solaris 10 the GNU utils are not integrated by default. This worked however.

Answer (score 16):

You can get the random number through `urandom`

`head -200 /dev/urandom | cksum`

Output:

`3310670062 52870`

To retrieve the one part of the above number.

`head -200 /dev/urandom | cksum | cut -f1 -d " "`

Then the output is

`3310670062`

Comment: `head -200` (or its POSIX equivalent `head -n 100`) returns the first 200 *lines* of `/dev/urandom`. `/dev/urandom` is not a text file, that command could return from 200 bytes (all 0x0a ones, LF in ASCII) to infinity (if the 0xa byte happens never to be returned) but values between 45k and 55k being the most likely. cksum returns a 32bit number, so it's pointless to get more than 4 bytes from `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: So why not `dd bs=200 count=1 2>/dev/null` to obtain EXACTLY 200 bytes of random data, instead of `head`?

Comment: For bash compatible i.e.<0, 32767>: `$(($(dd if=/dev/urandom count=1 2> /dev/null | cksum | cut -d' ' -f1) % 32768))`. Source: https://mdk.fr/blog/bashism-how-to-generate-random-number-without-random.html

Comment: As @StéphaneChazelas noted, cksum's most significant bit can be limited in size because it yields values from 0-4294967295 (2³²-1). Consider `head -c200 /dev/urandom |cksum |awk '{printf "%d", $1 % 10e8}'` instead, which grabs 200 random bytes rather than lines and provides random numbers from 0 to 999999999. To specify a maximum size up to 4294967295, change the modulo to that value plus one, like `head -c200 /dev/urandom |cksum |awk '{printf "%d", $1 % 256}'` for random numbers from 0-255.

Comment: Oops! `-c` isn't in [Posix head](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html), so you'll have to use `dd` as noted above.

Answer (score 14):

To generate a random integer variable between 5 and 10 (including both), use

```
echo $(( RANDOM % (10 - 5 + 1 ) + 5 ))
```

`%` works as a modulo operator.

There are probably better ways to convert the random variable `$RANDOM` to a specific range. Do not use this for cryptographic applications or in cases you need real, equal-distributed random variables (like for simulations).

Comment: In many shell implementations that do have $RANDOM (especially older ones, especially bash), that's not very random. In most shells, the number is between 0 and 65535, so any range whose width is not a power of two will have probability distribution discrepency. (in this case, numbers 5 to 8 will have a probability of 10923/65536, while 9 and 10 will have a probability of 10922/65536). The wider the range, the bigger the discrepency.

Comment: Sorry, that's 32767 not 65535, so the calculation above is wrong (and it's actually worse).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I had this in mind as I wrote that there are better ways...

Answer (score 8):

`# echo $(( $RANDOM % 256 ))` will produce a "random" number between 0-255 in modern *sh dialects.

Comment: Looks similar to [this other answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140752/117549) from 2 years ago.

Comment: This is subject to [the pigeonhole problem](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx) (TL;DR: some outcomes are more likely than others) if, instead of 256, you use a value that doesn't divide 32768 equally.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the `UUID` (on Linux) can be used to retrieve the random number

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid
cdd52826-327d-4355-9737-895f58ad11b4
```

To get the random number between `70` and `100`

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 awk -F - '{print(("0x"$1) % 30 + 70)}
   ' /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid
```

Answer (score 6):

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-fA-F0-9' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1
```

This will generate an 8 digits long hexadecimal number.

Comment: you can probably replace `fold -w 8 | head -n 1` with `head -c 8` in most cases

Answer (score 5):

Distribution is good:

```
for (( i = 1 ; i <= 100000 ; i++ )) do echo $(( RANDOM % (20 - 10 + 1 ) + 10 )) ; done | sort -n | uniq -c
```

Gives:

```
  count value

   9183 10
   9109 11
   8915 12
   9037 13
   9100 14
   9138 15
   9125 16
   9261 17
   9088 18
   8996 19
   9048 20
```

Answer (score 2):

To stay entirely within bash and use the `$RANDOM` variable but avoid the uneven distribution:

```
#!/bin/bash
range=10 
floor=20

if [ $range -gt 32768 ]; then
echo 'range outside of what $RANDOM can provide.' >&2
exit 1 # exit before entering infinite loop
fi 

max_RANDOM=$(( 2**15/$range*$range ))
r=$RANDOM
until [ $r -lt $max_RANDOM ]; do
r=$RANDOM
done
echo $(( r % $range + $floor ))
```

This example would provide random numbers from 20 through 29.

Explanation: Any `$RANDOM` result greater than `2**15/$range*$range` is in an incomplete modulus fold within which the result of `$r % $range` has a max value of `2**15%$range`, so results from 0 to `2**15%$range` have weight of `2**15/$range+1` and the value above have a weight of just `2**15/$range`. The worst case scenario of the poor distribution is when the `2**15/$range` is 1 and `2**15%$range` is not 0. Here, we can see clearly the problem when the range is 2/3 of `2**15`, where half the results have twice the probability:

```
$ range=$((2**15*2/3)); for (( i=0; i<10000; i++)); \
> do [ $((RANDOM%range) -le $((range/2)) ] \
> && ((le_10922++)) || ((gt_10922++)) ; done; \
> echo le_10922 $le_10922; echo gt_10922 $gt_10922 
le_10922 6748
gt_10922 3253
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using RANDOM**

```
MAX=999999                      #Upper Range
MIN=100000                      #Lower Range
DIFF=$((MAX-MIN+1))             #+1 to inlcude upper limit
R=$(($(($RANDOM%$DIFF))+MIN))
```

**Using SHUF**

```
MIN=1000
MAX=9999
COUNT=1                         #count of Random Numbers to be generated
shuf -i $MIN-$MAX -n $COUNT
shuf -i 1000-9999 -n 1
```

**Using /dev/random**

```
od -An -N2 -i /dev/random       #Generates a 2 byte Number, -N2=Generates 2 Random Number btween range 0-65535
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this portably is with `od` (there's no way to do it in portable POSIX shell without an external command, but at least this solution only has one such call). Here's a complete function you can use:

```bash
# Usage: random [[MIN] MAX]
# Display a random number from MIN (def=0) to MAX (def=2^32-1) (inclusive)
random() {
  n=$(od -An -N4 -tu /dev/urandom) || return $?
  case $# in
    ( 0 ) echo $n ;;                                  # min=0  max=4294967295
    ( 1 ) echo $(( n % ($1 + 1) )) ;;                 # min=0  max=$1
    ( 2 ) echo $(( n % ($2 + 1 - $1) + $1 )) ;;       # min=$1 max=$2
  esac
}
```

This generates a random unsigned integer and scopes it to optionally specified minimum and maximum values.

Examples:

```
$ random      # a random integer between 0 and 4294967295 (2³²-1)
102618
$ random 5    # a random integer between 0 and 5
5
$ random 1 5  # a random integer between 1 and 5
3
```

We all love one-liners, right? I managed to wedge this into 80 characters:

```
random(){ echo $(($(od -An -N4 -tu /dev/random)${1+%(${2+$2- }$1+1)${2++$1}}));}
```

(Explanation removed for being too verbose, see [revision 3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/766331/3) for detail.)