# improve mock data generation

Tags: performance, date, csv, random

I'm trying to generate csv with mock data

```
for i in {1..1000000..1}
do 
  echo "$i,$(date -d "2017-08-01 + $(shuf -i 1-31 -n 1) days" +'%Y-%m-%d')" >> $F
done;
```

looping from 1 to million and generating unique id & **random** date

but it works very slowly, is there any one-liner to make it parallel?

Comment: you don't *really* want it parallel; you just want it faster, right?

Comment: also, if I'm reading this correctly, you're just generating dates in August -- is this your *actual* use-case, or has it been simplified? Otherwise, you could just generate (one million divided by 31) entries for each date, then shuffle them.

Comment: relating only: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140750/generate-random-numbers-in-specific-range

Comment: also interesting reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/323845/117549

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See very end for end result.

```
for i in {1..1000000..1}
do 
  echo "$i,$(date -d "2017-08-01 + $(shuf -i 1-31 -n 1) days" +'%Y-%m-%d')" >> $F
done;
```

Shell loops are slow, and there are two main things that makes this particular loop extra slow:

1. Opening and appending to a file in each iteration.
2. Two executions of external utilities (`shuf` and `date`) in each iteration. The `echo` is likely built into the shell, so that incurs less overhead.

---

The output redirection is most easily remedied:

```
for i in {1..1000000..1}
do 
  echo "$i,$(date -d "2017-08-01 + $(shuf -i 1-31 -n 1) days" +'%Y-%m-%d')" 
done >"$F"
```

This only open the output file once and keeps it open for the duration of the loop.

---

The rest of the code can be done more efficiently with `awk` and GNU `date` (since you're using `shuf` I presume that you are on a Linux system, which means it's pretty likely that `date` is in fact GNU `date`).

```
awk 'END { for (i=0;i<100;++i) { printf("2017-08-01 + %d days\n", 1+int(31*rand())) }}' /dev/null
```

This thing generates 100 lines like

```
2017-08-01 + 22 days
2017-08-01 + 31 days
2017-08-01 + 11 days
2017-08-01 + 27 days
2017-08-01 + 27 days
2017-08-01 + 20 days
(etc.)
```

Let's feed these into GNU `date`. GNU `date` has this flag, `-f`, that lets us batch feed it with multiple date specifications, for example those outputted by our `awk` program:

```
awk 'END { for (i=0;i<100;++i) { printf("2017-08-01 + %d days\n", 1+int(31*rand())) }}' /dev/null |
date -f - +'%Y-%m-%d'
```

Now we get

```
2017-08-23
2017-08-27
2017-08-21
2017-08-29
2017-08-25
2017-08-17
2017-08-07
(etc.)
```

Then it's just a matter of adding the unique ID (a sequential integer) to each line:

```
awk 'END { for (i=0;i<100;++i) { printf("2017-08-01 + %d days\n", 1+int(31*rand())) }}' /dev/null |
date -f - +'%Y-%m-%d' |
awk -vOFS=',' '{ print NR, $0 }'
```

This gives you

```
1,2017-08-06
2,2017-08-17
3,2017-08-25
4,2017-08-28
5,2017-08-14
6,2017-08-15
7,2017-08-17
8,2017-08-10
9,2017-08-16
10,2017-08-08
(etc.)
```

And now we're done. And in the process, I totally forgot we had a shell loop. Turns out it's not needed.

Just crank up the `100` to whatever value you want, and adjust the random number generator to fit your needs.  `rand()` returns a floating point value such that 0 <= number < 1.

---

Obviously, if you just want random dates in August (a month with 31 days), you may bypass `date` altogether:

```
awk 'END { for (i=1;i<=100;++i) { printf("%d,2017-08-%02d\n", i, 1+int(31*rand())) }}' /dev/null
```

With GNU `awk` and Mike's `awk` (`mawk`), but not with BSD `awk`, you may even do proper date handling directly in `awk`:

```
awk 'END { for (i=1;i<=100;++i) { printf("%d,%s\n", i, strftime("%Y-%m-%d", 1501545600 + int(2678400*rand()),1 )) }}' /dev/null
```

Now we're dealing with Unix timestamps rather than with days though. 1501545600 corresponds to "Tue Aug  1 00:00:00 UTC 2017" and there are 2678400 seconds in 31 days.

Answer (score 1):

```
# A "random" date between 2000-01-01 and 2025-12-28
# Only uses day 01 to 28 
rand_date() {
    printf "%4d-%02d-%02d" $((RANDOM%25+2000)) $((RANDOM%12+1)) $((RANDOM%28+1))
}

csv_data() {
    for ((i=1; i<="$1"; i++)); do printf "%d,%s\n" $i $(rand_date); done
}
```

```
$ time (csv_data 1000000 > data.csv)
real    7m26.683s
user    0m36.376s
sys 1m57.768s
```

Perl's probably faster, let's try it

```
$ cat data.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
$, = ",";
$\ = "\n";

sub rand_date {
    sprintf "%4d-%02d-%02d", int(rand(25))+2000, int(rand(12))+1, int(rand(28))+1;
}

sub csv_data {
    my $n = shift;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
        print $i, rand_date();
    }
}

csv_data(1_000_000);
```

```
$ time (perl data.pl > data.csv)

real    0m0.881s
user    0m0.876s
sys 0m0.004s
```

Hmm, yeah, a bit faster...